# What OS should I use for sandboxing/running viruses designed for IoT devices?

Tags: malware, sandbox, honeypot

I have a telnet and ssh honeypot (more specifically, cowrie). Most viruses I get there are designed for routers, cameras, etc...

The virtualization software I am using is VirtualBox, and I am using it with cuckoo sandbox, which also supports the android emulator.

Here is the output of the file command on these viruses:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

My questions:

1. To run these viruses what OS should I use? Should I use the android emulator?
2. Is there any way to emulate router/IoT device firmware in VirtualBox (or any other software)?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would be aware of is CSR 1000v which can be run in VMWare.  Try following these instructions.

https://techandtrains.com/2014/01/09/installing-cisco-csr-1000v-in-virtualbox/

Comment: You mean VirtualBox? I am going to try it, thanks.

Comment: let me know if you get it to work